# Filter one record in table with Request ID

Tags: php, recursion, laravel-5, eloquent, recursive-query

I have tabel `request_process` as follows:

```
requestID Status
1            0
1            1
1            2
2            0
2            1
```

I want to get one row per request with maximum status but only those rows whose status for request is not 2

I want to apply this on where clause of query

```
$UserRequests = UserRequests::leftJoin('request_process', function($join){
$join->on('user_requests.id', '=', 'request_id')->where('status', '!=',2);})
->select('*')   
->get();
```

Comment: What's the name of the model for `request_process` table?

Comment: @vivek_23 RequestProcess

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$UserRequests = UserRequests::leftJoin('request_process','request_process.request_id','=','user_requests.id')
   ->where('request_process.status', '!=',2)
   ->select('*')
   ->get();
```

Comment: It not gives required results and get blank if there is not row in `request_process` table

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam then want u want i don't understand

Comment: I want all `users_request` table record with `request_process` to get one row per request with maximum status but only those rows whose status for request is not 2

Answer (score 0):

- We filter all rows which doesn't have this max status and do a `group by` on `request_process.requestID` and use an aggregate function `max()` to receive max status for each user request process.

**SQL:**

```
<?php

$max_status = 2; // hard coded but you need more tables to make this more flexible.

$UserRequests =  UserRequests::leftJoin('request_process','user_requests.id','=','request_process.request_id')
                    ->select('user_requests.*',DB::raw('max(request_process.status) as status'))
                    ->where('request_process.status','!=',$max_status)
                    ->groupBy('request_process.requestID')
                    ->get();

dd($UserRequests);
```

Comment: `leftjoin` required two parameters atleast

Comment: `Group By` clause is not do able as we have to list all required columns in it

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Fixed the leftJoin issue. Also, can you let me know the required columns in your select statement?